# Spinning 3D Scatterplot in R - Crashes

Tags: r, 3d, scatter-plot

I'm trying to create a 3D rotating scatterplot in R using the package  Rcmdr:

```
ParticlePos=read.table('FILE.dat',header=T,fill=T)
library(Rcmdr)
attach(mtcars)
scatter3d(ParticlePos[,1],ParticlePos[,2],ParticlePos[,3],xlab=expression(x),ylab=expression(y),zlab=expression(z),pch=19, col="red", size=3)
```

but it keeps crashing. It seems that it's opening up an XQuartz (v. 2.7.4, OS X 10.8) window and plotting it correctly, but after about a half second it closes leaving me with nothing. I'm fairly certain all of the appropriate dependencies and such are downloaded.

Would anyone have any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: FILE.dat is simply a test file with 100 random (x,y,z) coordinate triplets in space separated format, each between -1 and 1. But I will check with the example data.

Comment: If you are not using rgl_0.93.935 you should upgrade now and re-test. However; the most recent version is at R-forge: http://download.r-forge.r-project.org/bin/macosx/leopard/contrib/latest/rgl_0.93.940.tgz

Comment: I mention this because there is an email thread this morning on the R-SIG-Mac Mailing List about crashes with 'rgl' and Rob Goedman pointed to the more recent version as a reason he might unable to reproduce the crash. (Turned out rgl was crashing with X11 and not with XQuartz 2.7.4,.)

Comment: I checked and rgl 0.93.935 is indeed installed.

Comment: Unable to reproduce with that version of rgl, OSX 10.7.5 and `ParticlePos <-data.frame(x=rnorm(100), y=rnorm(100), z=rnorm(100))`. Bug reports should include a reproducible example and full details of versions. I should have used `library(car)`, since 'Rcmdr' is not needed and `scatter3d` is in 'car'..